# Merging sqlite databases through a bash script

Tags: bash, sqlite

Thanks to previous SO posts I can now merge sqlite databases.

But I want to run this merging in an automatic way using a bash script,

I have tried various ways and here is my latest and most complete fail:

```
## DB to merge
I1=d1.db
I2=d2.db

## Command to run
CMD='attach \'d2.db\' as toMerge; BEGIN; insert into sae select * from toMerge.sae; COMMIT; detach toMerge;'
echo $CMD

## Pass to sqlite
sqlite3 $I1 $CMD
```

Two issues meet here:

1- passing a bash variable (here d2.db). I had tried with the quote function as well:

```
CMD='attach quote('$I2') as toMerge; BEGIN; insert into sae select * from toMerge.sae; COMMIT; detach toMerge;'
```

2- the * in the select command that is interpreted in the bash way, hence the single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works

```
d1=d1.db
d2=d2.db
sqlite3 "$d1" <<!
attach database "$d2" as m;
insert into sae select * from m.sae;
detach m;
!
```

using a [heredoc](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Comment: it's a delimiter, `<<EOF` is also commonly used

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.db" -exec sqlite3 {} .dump \; | sqlite3 new_db
```