# Join two chrome history files into one with sqlite from bash script

Tags: bash, sqlite

I am generating a new chrome history file every day and I would like to take two of these daily files and join them together to make one contiguous history file.

The two history files do not share any of the same data from the same time but i have been unsuccessful with basic dumping and piping in. I was hoping that similar files would combine without collision but i was wrong.

```
sqlite3 History1 .dump | sqlite3 FullHistory
```

Success because the FullHistory file did not exist

```
sqlite3 History2 .dump | sqlite3 FullHistory
```

Errors. I'll try to list one of each error but in reality there are multiple of the same for each line.

```
table meta already exists
UNIQUE constraint failed: meta.key
table downloads already exists
UNIQUE constraint failed: downloads.id
table downloads_url_chains already exists
UNIQUE constraint failed: downloads_url_chains.id, downloads_url_chains.chain_index
table downloads_slices already exists
table typed_url_sync_metadata already exists
table "urls" already exists
UNIQUE constraint failed: urls.id
table visits already exists
table visit_source already exists
table keyword_search_terms already exists
table segments already exists
UNIQUE constraint failed: segments.id
table segment_usage already exists
UNIQUE constraint failed: segment_usage.id
index urls_url_index already exists
visits_url_index already exists
index visits_from_index already exists
index visits_time_index already exists
index segments_name already exists
index segments_url_id already exists
index segment_usage_time_slot_segment_id already exists
index segments_usage_seg_id already exists
index keyword_search_terms_index1 already exists
index keyword_search_terms_index2 already exists
index keyword_search_terms_index3 already exists
```

I am just wanting to create a single file, the same as if i had let Chrome generate the History file itself for two days.

I obviously have no actual knowledge of databases and would just like a snippet of code that i can add to my bash script that will join the two files together.

Thanks

Comment: You can't merge the databases dump, unless reprocessing the data, knowing the schema, rematch the indexes references between tables. Even if you manage to remove the duplicate table creation statements, the data inside tables need to be re-indexed, and all indexes references need to be updated to the corresponding new values.

Comment: You are making this sound like a daunting task when i don't think a computer will even need to put much effort or time into merging two sqlite databases approximately with 400 entries each. Unless you were meaning that for doing by hand, which is not what i was looking for. The question is how because I just don't know how to do it.

I keep coming across solutions like this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637071/merging-sqlite-databases-through-a-bash-script) but they're Greek to me because i don't know what i am doing. The simplicity of the solutions look promising to me though

Comment: If you glue cars together, it will not make a bus. Same as if you glue SQLite dumps, it will not make a working database. Like if you try to make a bus from multiple cars, you will have to re-arrange parts, remove duplicate, merging two database will require your re-arrange records, fix indexes and references to index. Now if you feel like learning enough SQL, that is an easy language, examine the SQLite DB, tables structure. You will surely see by yourself what need to be done to merge the data. It is not a daunting task, but require some involvement, understanding the layout and effort.